# Why is a purging process necessary for static firing test of liquid rocket engines?

Tags: liquid-fuel, engineering, testing, engines, development

In Chapter 7 of **Modern Engineering for Design of Liquid propellant Rocket Engines** by *Huzel and Huang*, mentions the following engine cut off procedure.

> The cutoff sequence usually consists of 
>   shutoff of subsystems ....
>
> ... and, in the **case of 
>   test firings, postfiring securing (purges, flushes).**

Why is it important to purge? And how is the system purged- only the fuel line *or* both the propellant feed lines?

Answer (score 10):

Purging is done to remove residual fuel from the lines. This is normally done using nitrogen gas.

https://www.grc.nasa.gov/www/retf/textFiles/lessonsRocketEngineTesting.html

Residual fuel and oxidiser represents a combustion hazard - it could leak out or evaporate and start a fire. Also, if your oxidiser is something like nitric acid or dinitrogen tetroxide or (god forbid) some kind of fluorine-based oxidiser, that can create a severe safety hazard to the engineers working on or cleaning up the rocket engine after a test.

Comment: Thanks for the informative link. What I don’t understand is the requirement of a prestart purge mentioned?

Comment: I guess that's to remove anything that accumulated in the time since it was last fired. Dust and mice and stuff. I may not remember this correctly, but in the book Ignition!, a rocket test firing disturbed a family of bats that had taken residence in a rocket chamber.

Comment: You'd also want to purge all the oxygen from the fuel system before you put any fuel in.

Comment: and anything organic from the oxidiser system

Comment: Purging also removes any on-going leakage through seals, etc from the engine before starting. Some seals don't fully "seal" until the system is pressurized.